# How to access provider value when using useContext hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { MyContext, MyProvider } from './Context'

const MasterContainer  = () =>{
    const ctx = useContext(MyContext)

    return (
        <MyProvider>
            {ctx}
            <MyContext.Consumer>
                {context=><div>{context.age}</div>}
            </MyContext.Consumer>  
        </MyProvider>
    )
}

export default MasterContainer
```

ctx right now is returning undefined when i actually want to pull ctx.age

```
import React from 'react'


export const MyContext = React.createContext("dude")

export class MyProvider extends React.Component{
    state = {
        name: 'Hello',
        age: 12
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Basically i want to access the values of my state in my provider using hooks, how do i go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an very simple use case of `createContext`-method and updating current context value. [CodeSandbox-example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/how-to-access-provider-value-when-using-usecontext-hook-lo6ki)

Important to notice here, like described in [React.js createContext-method documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext), context value will be matched to the closest matching `Provider` above in tree.

> **React.createContext** - Creates an Context object. When React renders a component that subscribes to this Context object it will read the current context value from the closest matching Provider above it in the tree.

Also keep in mind as stated in docs, default value argument is only used if no matching Provider is found.

> The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. This can be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them. Note: passing undefined as a Provider value does not cause consuming components to use defaultValue.

Comment: Is there a reason why there are 3 levels? Why can't i wrap App with <Context> within the return itself. Why must i have this buffer component called Root

Comment: You do not need to wrap it into tree depth of 3 if you do not wish so. This was just for an example and to wrap this component logic into re-usable context logic. You could'v just repalce `{this.props.children}` with any of your components. https://codesandbox.io/s/z245pok68l I updated the example to demonstrate this.

Comment: The defaultValue argument got me. It's counterintuitive for me.

Comment: Unfortunately the codesandbox url doesnt work :(. 404 error is thrown.

Comment: @johnsam Codesandbox-example had been removed at some point, I created you a new reference repo to Codesandbox and updated to link for you. Here same url https://codesandbox.io/embed/how-to-access-provider-value-when-using-usecontext-hook-lo6ki

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in React 16.7.0 and ReactDOM 16.7.0, useContext does not seem to be working. For functional components, this worked for me:

```
// Theme context, default to light theme
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

// Signed-in user context
const UserContext = React.createContext({
  name: 'Guest',
});

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {signedInUser, theme} = this.props;

    // App component that provides initial context values
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
        <UserContext.Provider value={signedInUser}>
          <Layout />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar />
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
}

// A component may consume multiple contexts
function Content() {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {theme => (
        <UserContext.Consumer>
          {user => (
            <ProfilePage user={user} theme={theme} />
          )}
        </UserContext.Consumer>
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

For class-based components, it is even simpler:

```
   import {ThemeContext} from './theme-context';

class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    let theme = this.context;
    return (
      <button
        {...props}
        style={{backgroundColor: theme.background}}
      />
    );
  }
}
ThemedButton.contextType = ThemeContext;

export default ThemedButton;
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html